# changing from DHCP to static (reboot breaks what ifup fixed)

Tags: networking, server, static-ip

Fresh install of 16.04.1 as a virtual machine, didn't catch the DHCP dialog fast enough during install, am trying to set it as static now. I've edited the file /etc/networking/interfaces: If I reboot the server, it has no network.

If I log into the console, and issue the command

```
ifdown ens33
```

with appropriate permissions, I'm told ens33 is not configured. When I immediately run

```
ifup ens33
```

It exits normally and I have my expected static IP until the next reboot.

DHCP, for the ~two boots it was used, came up fine and registered with our company's internal DNS servers. Currently, the relevant part of interfaces reads:

```
iface ens33 inet static
address 10.1.96.36
netmask 255.255.255.0
gateway 10.1.96.1
dns-search ourdomain.org
dns-nameservers 10.1.96.13 10.1.96.89
```

What file needs to be edited, still?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want the interface to come up *auto*matically on boot, you need:

```
auto ens33
iface ens33 inet static
address 10.1.96.36
netmask 255.255.255.0
gateway 10.1.96.1
dns-search ourdomain.org
dns-nameservers 10.1.96.13 10.1.96.89
```